# How to iterate through enum type while skipping some values?

Tags: c#, enums, iteration

The key part of my question is the skipping. I plan to use an enum type that has about 20 elements. I want to iterate through this set but need to skip an element or two each time. What to skip is known in advance. A comparable example is the enum type that consists of all letters of the alphabet, and when iterating, I want to skip all the vowels.

How should I code the iteration in an elegant/efficient way? Should I make a separate set of elements consisting of vowels? I have no code to show because I am just thinking about the problem.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
var query = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
    .Cast<MyEnum>()
    .Except(new MyEnum[] { MyEnum.A, MyEnum.E });
foreach (MyEnum item in query) {
    ...
}
```

You need to cast in order to get the magic of LINQ. `Except` alone will not do it.

---

UPDATE:

I got another idea. You can define the enum with the `FlagsAttribute` and define the regular values as powers of 2, what is most easily achieved with the bitwise shift left operator `<<`. Starting with C# 7.0, you can also use binary literals like `0b_0000_0000_0010_0000`. Then it is possible to combine existing values to form new values.

```
[Flags]
enum MyEnum
{
    None = 0,
    A = 1 << 0,
    B = 1 << 1,
    C = 1 << 2,
    D = 1 << 3,
    E = 1 << 4,
    ...
    X = 1 << 23,
    Y = 1 << 24,
    Z = 1 << 25,
    Vowels = A | E | I | O | U
}
```

Now, you can formulate the query like this

```
IEnumerable<MyEnum> query = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
    .Cast<MyEnum>()
    .Where(x => (x & MyEnum.Vowels) == MyEnum.None);
foreach (MyEnum item in query) {
    ...
}
```

The advantage over the first solution is, that you can perform the test with a single bitwise AND-operation.

You can define up to 32 powers of two. If you need more, you can define the base type of the enum as `long` and use up to 64 flag values (plus combinations of existing flag values).

```
[Flags]
enum MyEnum : long
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is probably the most complete answer. The easiest thing to do from here is to specify various collections of Enums that you would want to skip, that way you can have those skip collections saved and can pass in whatever criteria you want in Except.

Comment: Yes, and you can also keep various queries.

Comment: I added another solution using only a bitwise AND to make the test. It does not require any arrays or HashSets for the exceptional values. Please see my update.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably just use LINQ - use `Enum.GetValues` (or use [Unconstrained Melody](http://unconstrained-melody.googlecode.com) - a type-safe generic enum/delegate library I wrote) to get all the values, then express which values to keep/skip via a `Where`clause.

If you're only skipping specific values, a `HashSet` or something similar may be useful (not worth it if you're only skipping one, of course) - if you're skipping based on a condition, then a full-blown predicate is called for.

For example:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AllBut<T>(T skipped) where T : struct
{
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    return AllBut<T>(t => !comparer.Equals(skipped, t));
}

public static IEnumerable<T> AllBut<T>(Func<T, bool> skipPredicate) where T : struct
{
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
               .Cast<T>()
               .Where(t => skipPredicate(t));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would make a separate set of elements consisting of vowels, and then take the set difference between the two sets using LINQ.

```
int[] vowels = {Letters.A, Letters.E, Letters.I, Letters.O, Letters.U};
IEnumerable<int> consonant = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Letters)).Except(vowels);
foreach (int consonant in consonants)
{
    // Do something with each consonant
}
```